# Node-Yelp with Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

I'm sure I'll get some laughs here for this but I'm learning....

So I found node-yelp on Yelp's api docs. Looks like this. https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp

```
// Request API access: http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_access
var Yelp = require('yelp');

var yelp = new Yelp({
  consumer_key: 'consumer-key',
  consumer_secret: 'consumer-secret',
  token: 'token',
  token_secret: 'token-secret',
});

// See http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
yelp.search({ term: 'food', location: 'Montreal' })
.then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});

// See http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business
yelp.business('yelp-san-francisco')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

yelp.phoneSearch({ phone: '+15555555555' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

// A callback based API is also available:
yelp.business('yelp-san-francisco', function(err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

I'm wondering if I could somehow use this in a factory.... Is this the wrong way to go about using this node package?

```
let Yelp = require('yelp');

namespace app.Factory {
    export class YelpFactory {
        public yelp;

        public search (){
            this.yelp.search({}).then((data)=>{

            })
        }
        constructor(){
            this.yelp = new Yelp({
                consumer_key: process.env.YELP_CONSUMER_KEY,
                consumer_secret: process.env.YELP_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                token: process.env.YELP_CONSUMER_TOKEN,
                token_secret: process.env.YELP_TOKEN_SECRET
            });
        }
    }
    angular.module('app').factory('YelpFactory', YelpFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you are trying to do is have a preconfigured instance of `Yelp`. If that's the case, I would just use an injected singleton of yelp without the clutter of reimplementing the yelp api:

```
let Yelp = require('yelp');

namespace app.Factory {
  angular.module('app').factory('yelp', () => {
    return new Yelp({
                  consumer_key: process.env.YELP_CONSUMER_KEY,
                  consumer_secret: process.env.YELP_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                  token: process.env.YELP_CONSUMER_TOKEN,
                  token_secret: process.env.YELP_TOKEN_SECRET
              });
  });
}
```